# changing method signature in java without affecting other implementations of an interface

Tags: java

Let's say I have a Java class called `A` and an interface called `I`. The `A` class implements the interface `I`. Interface `I` has the following method definition `byte[] x(String in)`. The interface `I` is also implemented by other classes like `B`, `C`, `D` and so on.

Now let's say I want to send an extra argument for the implementation of `x` method from `A`. Let's say I want to have a new definition, something like `byte[] x(String in, OutputStream os)`.

Is there any way to pass that `OutputStream os` in the `x` method without affecting other implementations? The problem is that if I make a change in `I`, I have to make this change in all implementations which is not OK. If I choose to change the `x` method signature, I will have to change it in all the methods and pass the second argument everywhere in the code.

That `OutputStream` must come from a `@Controller` and this `OutputStream` must be a different stream (a stream per request).

My implementations are `@Component` used in `@Service`.

Do you have any suggestions on how to pass that stream only to my `A` class for `x`?

The actual purpose of `x` is to write the returned bites to generate a file. Sending the `OutputStream` will somehow determine the return type to become `void` because data will be sent directly to the stream.

Comment: Define it in `A`, check if your object is an instance of `A`, cast and invoke.

Comment: I would've chosen this solution in case my strategy pattern hadn't broke.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do it in Java 8 using default methods in interfaces:

```
public interface I {
    byte[] x(String in);
    default byte[] x(String in, OutputStream os) {
        return x(in);    
    }
}
```

So, all classes which implement **I** contain implementation of old method x(String in) and inherit default implementation of new method x(String in, OutputStream os) from interface. You can override and reimplement the new method only in one class where you need a specific behavior for this method.

An **update** for author's explanation of his problem in comments (`A` generates big byte[] object, so, only in this `A` class we want to implement optimization by writing directly to OutputStream):

```
public interface I {
    byte[] x(String in);
    default void x(String in, OutputStream os) {
        try {
            os.write(x(in));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //handle it
        }
    }
}
```

So, you call x(String in, OutputStream os) from your controller, in case of classes `B`, `C`, ... original implementation will be called and written to output stream, while for A we will call optimized version without creation of big intermediate objects. I changed return value of `x(String in, OutputStream os)`, because in that case you have no need to produce `byte[]`, you just write to output stream in implementations.

Comment: I like the solution but how I am going to know to call `x(in, out)` instead of `x(in)`? Right now I have something like in `MyService` like `saveF(in){... return x(in); }`

Comment: @tzortzik I'm not sure that I got you, but... `saveF(in){out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); return x(in, out);}`. If you have non-default implementation of `x(in, out)` in this class - you will call you overridden version. If no - you will actually call old `x(in)`.

Comment: My problem is actually two. The first one is the need to pass the `OutputStream` only for `A` class so that I won't have to change the code in many places. This issue may be solved with your solution but here comes the second problem. How do I pass `OutputStream` from my `@Controller` to `A`?

Comment: Hm... just call new method and pass OutputStream from your controller :) Code in our controller: `I a = new IImpl(); a.x(str, out);` As a result - if `a` is entity of class where you overridden x(String, OutputStream) - reimplemented version will be called. In case of other classes - main old version will be called.

Comment: From my understanding you say that in the case you described, if I call `a.x(str, out)` on an instance of `C` it will automatically invoke `x(str)`? Is this possible? This is what I have now `I anyClassAOrBOrCOrD = myStrategyObject.x(str)`.

Comment: Yes, if you don't override default method in C and just call `x(str, out)` from Controller on `C` instance - `C#x(str)` will be called and returned from `default x(str, out)`

Comment: I haven't noticed you call of `x` inside the default method. Now I can say that here is another problem because the purpose of my change is removing the `byte[]` from `A` class because this causes an `OutOfMemory` exception. This `A` class is so special that it generates a big amount of data which I need to send to the user. This is the reason why I have to introduce streams. I am starting to see that there is no way around this but to add the stream parameter everywhere in my code.

Comment: @tzortzik Updated my answer with how I understood your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the definition of x in the interface without changing all classes that implement it.  You can add x with the additional parameter as a separate method, since it will just be an overloaded version of x.  However, you would not be able to call it when treating the instance of A as an I.

Comment: This is exactly the problem I have. How can I get this behavior? Maybe Decorator or Proxy patterns may help?